# Which handsets work with IP DECT base?

Tags: voip, telephony

My workplace uses an Ascom IP DECT base station (IPBS1), and Ascom handsets as well. We're looking to replace some broken handsets. The ones by Ascom, however, are rather expensive, and we're not altogether satisfied with their quality. I've been looking at handsets from other manufacturers which are much less expensive; however, I don't know if they will work with the base since I don't know anything about DECT, VOIP, etc.

I've perused the base's manual but found nothing on handset compatibility. How can I find out what kind of handset works with our base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All DECT handsets available share a common profile - the Generic Access Profile. So you should be able to use any DECT handset paired with your base station to make or receive calls. Other profiles however, are optional and mostly proprietary, so things like caller ID display, automatic date/time settings, the ability to choose the outbound line / set the outbound caller ID may or may not work.

This has absolutely nothing to do with VoIP BTW, DECT is a separate technology and your base station(s) use VoIP connections to forward the calls upstream (or receive and signal them from there), so the VoIP network boundary is at the base station, not at the handset.

Usually, manufacturers are not doing any compatibility tests with foreign base stations or handsets, so you will have a hard time finding any information on compatibility beyond the GAP. The easiest way would be to either just try, or, if you do not feel like trying, just add another base station from a vendor of your liking (Siemens for example is selling 1-line versions of DECT base stations with their IP phone line and has a 4-line version sold separately as Gigaset N510 pro).

Answer (score 1):

We're running Ascom IP DECT and IP DECT Gateways on our company. With Cisco CUCM as PBX.
Works fine with Ascom and works very well also with AAstra models.
We've confirmed function with the following Gigaset models:

Gigaset C430
Works: Missed calls, Gateway roaming, voicemail led indication, 
Not working: Roaming on IP DECT, Time and date (after restart of phone it's reseted to default)

Gigaset S650h Pro
Works: Missed calls, Gateway roaming, voicemail led indication
Not working: Roaming on IP DECT, Time and date (after restart of phone it's reseted to default)